# Would a VR headset exacerbate myopia or could it be used to retrain the eyes?

Tags: vision, eyes

I've learned that there are [two primary hypotheses to explain myopia: not enough use of distance vision *or* not enough sunlight](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1964/has-increased-computer-use-led-to-increased-myopia)

If the distance between an eye and what it's focusing on is the primary cause, then having a VR screen inches away would seem like a recipe for exacerbating myopia.

However, since people with 20/20 vision can use VR headsets, while others need the maximum correction and still see everything out of focus, clearly there is something more than at play than simply focal distance between the eye and the screen.  Could this be used to help minimize, prevent, or possible reduce myopia?

Likewise, if the cause is primarily lack of sunlight, could sunny simulations be used to help minimize, prevent, or possible reduce myopia?  Or is the light produced too artificial?

Knowing that myopia is on the rise, and VR is going to be more prevalent in the near future, these seem like important relationships to understand.

Of course, it could be they are simply two factors of many; but they are extremely relevant to this question.

More recently, my ophthalmologist was adamant that I needed to follow the 20/20/20 rule, i.e. every 20 minutes focus on things more than 20 feet away for at least 20 seconds, which leads me to believe he at least subscribes to the distance hypothesis.

Comment: Personal medical and health questions are [off-topic](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site.

Comment: This would make an interesting question when all reference to self would be removed. Voted to close but +1 for the question.

Comment: I made some edits to the phrasing of the question. Please check if this still reflects your intentions and rollback if required.

Comment: @MarchHo - Thank you.  That reflects my intentions perfectly!

Comment: When using VR headset your eyes focus on distant objects, not on the screen, that's the power of optics!

Comment: @szulat If you can find a citation for that, it would be a good answer. I am rather skeptical of that claim though.